# Torah verses with zero educational / Halachic value

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parshanut-theory

Informational non-uniformity of the Torah bothers me a lot, I'd rather expect from a holy book to be evenly informational (cf. Parshas Mishpotim for example). (*I remember asking a question once about that, I can't find it now.*)

Instead, we have long passages bearing no educational or Halahic (to learn something from it) value (Parshas Nessi'im for example) where verse after verse there are no interpretations, commentary or reference whatsoever.

Are there verses that are not interpreted by any any book? If yes, What is the importance of those passages? Does anybody mention that they were interpreted once and we forgot the interpretations?

Comment: You mention yourself that it could have any other value; what caused your assumption that the value of imparting information must be applicable to every verse?

Comment: Similar question in the [Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.99b.4)

Comment: As  many commentators have pointed out, every word in the Torah has value and significance. The pshat is not necessarily *informational value*. The example that you give (Parshas Nesi'im) shows this as the very fact that each nasi brought the exact same *korbon* teaches a profound lesson. In fact, the variation in the wording for the nasi of Yissachar is also a major lesson. Just because there is no *fact* that you can see immediately in a particular location does not mean that what was written is not required.

Comment: @chortkov2 I accept your comment, I changed the question. Every word IS informational albeit not educational or Halachic.

Comment: @ba Thank you, an interesting discussion. I changed the phrasing a bit to clarify my intention - every word is informational but many are superfluous. Form a Heavenly book I would expect a different "informational density", as in Parshas Mishpotim, for example, Mitzvah after Mitzvah. THe Sages in the Gemmorah take the usual approach - "we have no idea but if you deny it you're heretic". I understand.

Comment: "*every word in the Torah has value and significance*" - is a a-priori belief: "Since G-d gave us Torah and G-d is wise hence Torah is all significant letter-wise". On the other hand we hold that "דברה התורה כלשון ב"א" and because people use superfluous language, Torah also uses superfluous language, so we run into a contradiction. So Torah is Heavenly wise but it only looks humanly.

Comment: The pesukim “ויאמר השם אל משה לאמר” And “וידבר השם אל משה לאמר” are probably the most likely not to have commentaries comment on them.

Comment: ‘There are no stories in the Torah only laws’- Rogechover. Also see his commentary on the Torah.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a pasuk, word, letter, even in the little curve at the botton of the *yud* that does not have an education value or halachic value. I learned in a gemara (Menachos 29b) that when Moshe Rabenu went up to shamayim, he saw HaKodesh Baruch Hu making little crowns for the letters of the Torah. Moshe asked HaKodesh Baruch Hu, "What are these for?" HaKodesh Baruch Hu replied, "There will be a man named Akiva ben Yosef, who will be able to deduce a halacha from every little curve and crown of the letters of the Torah."
We learn from this gemara that there is nothing that doesn't have value in the Torah.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodea and thank you for your effort. Sometimes, we have a big gap between what we ought to believe and what we see in fact. You perfectly outlined our beliefs, we do *believe* that all the Torah is informational down to the Kutzo SHel Yod bears some practical importance but de-facto, large portions of the Torah are meaningless/informationless *to us*. Judaism, for example, would be no different if the story of Eliezer and Rivka of Nesiim's offerings were not repeated.